# Where to store static JSON data in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage

I have about 350 lines of static JSON data in my extension. That data is used in a content script and all of it is needed. It's a list of key-value pairs. Whenever a user clicks on the page, all keys are checked if they match a condition and the appropriate action is performed. Something like:

```
{
    "ABC": 323.32,
    "BDS": 23.12,
    "GTO": 96.52
}
```

Where is it best to put it? I came up with three ideas:

- Include it directly in the content script.
- Load it in an Event Page and use Message Passing to retrieve the data.
- Store it in a JSON file and *somehow* retrieve it with XHR. I don't think that one's possible, though.

I know about `localStorage` and I've seen Chrome's various other types of storage. However, they seem to be intended for data that is generated while the user is doing stuff with the extension.

My data is static. Once the extension is installed, it doesn't change. That is, until the extension receives an update and modifies it *eventually*.

Right now, the data is inside a content script. I think that's not great because it's loaded every time a page is opened while it doesn't change at all. For that reason, an Event Page seems more suitable. **However, is there something *designed* for this type of data?**

Comment: Is it actually JSON, or an Object literal?

Comment: This question is too broad. You haven't told us how you use the data. How much of the data do you actually need in each content script? Is it something which is loaded into a data structure and then you only access one piece of it in each content script? We need more information in order to be able to provide any evaluation of the good ways to store the data. Right now all we can do is toss out ideas for how it's *possible* to do it.

Comment: @Makyen edited.

Comment: If you *always* need *all* of it, *every* time the content script is loaded, then just keep it as an [Object literal / Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) in the content script. Anything else just adds complexity and additional processing requirements. if your *actual* source for the data is JSON, then you could have it as a JSON string in your content script, which you parse with `JSON.parse()`, but even that adds a bit of overhead.

Comment: What about Walk's suggestion with `chrome.storage.local` and `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` is that going to make things any better? At least the data would have already been loaded?

Comment: No, that's not any better. That data is stored as JSON internally. it's more processing to load it. You've said that you need *all* of it, *every* time a user clicks on the page. That's close enough to *always* needing *all* of it in *every* content script such that any possible savings of not having the Object in the content script on the relatively few times the user doesn't click in a page is outweighed by the additional processing needed.

Comment: If you wanted to perform the comparisons in the background script (send the click info to the background page and get back a response), that might be more memory efficient, but, that's really going to depend on how often you are needing to make such comparisons, and if you are willing to let the comparison happen in the background script. And that may still not be more efficient for 350x a 3 character string and a number. Either way, you're doing a *lot* better than those extension developers who load 85kiB of jQuery into every page, just to save a few characters in their own script.

Answer (score 7):

You CAN retrieve it with XHR or fetch. Use `chrome.extension.getURL` to get URL of your file.

This should work:

```
fetch(chrome.extension.getURL('/data.json'))
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function (jsonData) {
        console.log(jsonData);
    });
```

And you also have to add it to your manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "data.json"
],
```

Comment: This is only helpful if the data is seldom accessed. If it's needed in every content script, every time, this does not have any advantage over just storing it as an Object literal in the content script.

Comment: @Makyen agreed, I was mainly addressing third point of this question, where OP didn't think it was possible at all. In my opinion it would be better to store this data in `chrome.storage.local`, moving data there in `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` event when extensions is first installed or updated. Then you can retrieve information piece by piece when needed. Or store it as an object literal in background script and retrieve parts of it from content scripts as needed using messaging (it will occupy RAM though). I'm not confident enough to suggest that one particular method is the best.